# Display detailed info (may be in a popup window) as I click a name in a leaderboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a leaderboard here with four javascript tabs ,which display four different leaderboards when I click the tabs.
Please run the below code snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var block = _this.attr('href');
    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
    _this.parent().addClass("active");
    $(".leadboardcontent").hide();
    $(block).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
  background: #c1bdba;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}
.form {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 305px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a0b3b0;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #ff8566;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background: #ff5c33;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
/*--------------------
            Body
            --------------------*/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  min-height: 650px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
/*--------------------
            Leaderboard
            --------------------*/

.leaderboard {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  width: 285px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a404d, #181c26);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a404d, #181c26);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px rgba(62, 9, 11, 0.3);
}
.leaderboard h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 12px 13px 18px;
}
.leaderboard h1 svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.leaderboard ol {
  counter-reset: leaderboard;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.leaderboard ol li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  counter-increment: leaderboard;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  list-style: none;
}
.leaderboard ol li::before {
  content: counter(leaderboard);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #c24448;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: -9px;
  border-top: 10px solid #c24448;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -9px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
.leaderboard ol li small {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
.leaderboard ol li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fa6855;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fa6855;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1)::after {
  background: #fa6855;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #e0574f;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2)::after {
  background: #e0574f;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::after {
  border-top: 6px solid #ba4741;
  bottom: -7px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #d7514d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3)::after {
  background: #d7514d;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::after {
  border-top: 2px solid #b0433f;
  bottom: -3px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) {
  background: #c24448;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8)::after {
  background: #c24448;
  box-shadow: 0 -2.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::after {
  top: -9px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #993639;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: visible;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
  transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">

  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#weeklylb">Weekly LB</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#overalllb">Overall LB</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#defaulters">Defaulters</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#co-workers">Co-Workers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="weeklylb" class="leadboardcontent">

      <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>Weekly LB</mark>
            <small>315</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes</mark>
            <small>301</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
            <small>292</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
            <small>245</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
            <small>203</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
            <small>203</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
            <small>245</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
            <small>203</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>


      <svg style="display: none;">
        <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px" width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
          <path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
                              C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
                              C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
                              c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
                              c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
                              c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
                              c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
                              c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
                              c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
                              c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
                              C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
                              c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
                              L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
                              c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
                              C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
                              C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
                              c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z" />
        </symbol>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
      <div class="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>Overall LB</mark>
            <small>3115</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes1</mark>
            <small>3101</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight1</mark>
            <small>2192</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick1</mark>
            <small>2145</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox1</mark>
            <small>2103</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>And1rew Fox1</mark>
            <small>2103</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Tre1vor McCormick1</mark>
            <small>2145</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox1</mark>
            <small>2103</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- login tab end defaulters -->
    <div id="defaulters" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
      <div class="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>Defaulters</mark>
            <small>3115</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes2</mark>
            <small>31012</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight2</mark>
            <small>21922</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>And1rew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Tre1vor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- login tab end co-workers -->
    <div id="co-workers" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
      <div class="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>co-workers</mark>
            <small>3115</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes2</mark>
            <small>31012</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight2</mark>
            <small>21922</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>And1rew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Tre1vor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
  <!-- tab-content -->

</div>
<!-- /form -->

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Now,this leaderboard is working perfect.But i was trying to add some new feature here.

problem:
How to display info regarding a person from the leaderboard as I click his/her name. 
I have a link to an instance,similar to which I want to achieve.

link for an example : http://codepen.io/HannahF/pen/EKrbad

In this example ,if you click on the name of a person it will give details about that person.Similar to this,can we achieve in my page.

Kindly help,if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go buddy ! Check out this [codepen link.](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/ALzjGN) You just need to display a div with information you want to display. Currently i have binded it with on click. You can **add more transitions and css** to look it more better. Also dont forget to update the person name and points and other information according to the user which is clicked. Hope this helps :)

**Note** : If you have some time, i would suggest to have a look on [bootstrap modal here.](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var block = _this.attr('href');
    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
    _this.parent().addClass("active");
    $(".leadboardcontent").hide();
    $(block).fadeIn();
  });
  
  $('.leaderboard mark').on('click',function(){
    alert('something');  
    $('.rb-overlay').show();
    //Update username and email and other fields here.
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
  background: #c1bdba;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.rb-overlay {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  top:0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.form {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 305px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a0b3b0;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #ff8566;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background: #ff5c33;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
/*--------------------
            Body
            --------------------*/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  min-height: 650px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
/*--------------------
            Leaderboard
            --------------------*/

.leaderboard {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  width: 285px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a404d, #181c26);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a404d, #181c26);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px rgba(62, 9, 11, 0.3);
}
.leaderboard h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 12px 13px 18px;
}
.leaderboard h1 svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.leaderboard ol {
  counter-reset: leaderboard;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.leaderboard ol li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  counter-increment: leaderboard;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  list-style: none;
}
.leaderboard ol li::before {
  content: counter(leaderboard);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #c24448;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: -9px;
  border-top: 10px solid #c24448;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -9px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
.leaderboard ol li small {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
.leaderboard ol li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fa6855;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fa6855;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1)::after {
  background: #fa6855;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #e0574f;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2)::after {
  background: #e0574f;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::after {
  border-top: 6px solid #ba4741;
  bottom: -7px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #d7514d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3)::after {
  background: #d7514d;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::after {
  border-top: 2px solid #b0433f;
  bottom: -3px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) {
  background: #c24448;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8)::after {
  background: #c24448;
  box-shadow: 0 -2.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::after {
  top: -9px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #993639;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: visible;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
  transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">

  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#weeklylb">Weekly LB</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#overalllb">Overall LB</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#defaulters">Defaulters</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#co-workers">Co-Workers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="rb-overlay">
          <span class="rb-close">close</span>
          <span class="profile">
            <h2>Thea Kyriakos</h2>
            <p><strong>Email Address:</strong> theak@fakeemail.com</p>
            <p><strong>IM:</strong> theak</p>
            <p><strong>Member Since:</strong>12/02/2013</p>
          </span>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="weeklylb" class="leadboardcontent">

      <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>Weekly LB</mark>
            <small>315</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes</mark>
            <small>301</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
            <small>292</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
            <small>245</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
            <small>203</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
            <small>203</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
            <small>245</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
            <small>203</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>


      <svg style="display: none;">
        <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px" width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
          <path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
                              C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
                              C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
                              c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
                              c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
                              c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
                              c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
                              c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
                              c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
                              c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
                              C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
                              c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
                              L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
                              c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
                              C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
                              C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
                              c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z" />
        </symbol>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
      <div class="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>Overall LB</mark>
            <small>3115</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes1</mark>
            <small>3101</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight1</mark>
            <small>2192</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick1</mark>
            <small>2145</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox1</mark>
            <small>2103</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>And1rew Fox1</mark>
            <small>2103</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Tre1vor McCormick1</mark>
            <small>2145</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox1</mark>
            <small>2103</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- login tab end defaulters -->
    <div id="defaulters" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
      <div class="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>Defaulters</mark>
            <small>3115</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes2</mark>
            <small>31012</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight2</mark>
            <small>21922</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>And1rew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Tre1vor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- login tab end co-workers -->
    <div id="co-workers" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
      <div class="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>co-workers</mark>
            <small>3115</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes2</mark>
            <small>31012</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight2</mark>
            <small>21922</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>And1rew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Tre1vor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
  <!-- tab-content -->

</div>
<!-- /form -->

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro.I appreciate it.I will look into bootstarp modal .

Comment: @ShivamSharma you are welcome bro. we are here to build a great community at stack overflow. Please mark the answer if this solves what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have the details in a pop-up instead of changing the whole page- or maybe have the details appear at the side of the page when you hover over one of the names?

Comment: Thanks for the input.I need to include some more info like 7-8 parameters.So pop up will do but hover over wont be good.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this working [Demo - Jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/DineshV/bL062qys/1/)

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form">

  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#weeklylb">Weekly LB</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#overalllb">Overall LB</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#defaulters">Defaulters</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#co-workers">Co-Workers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="weeklylb" class="leadboardcontent">

      <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <mark>Weekly LB</mark>
            <small>315</small>
          </li>
          <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <mark>Brandon Barnes</mark>
            <small>301</small>
          </li>
          <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
            <small>292</small>
          </li>
          <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
            <small>245</small>
          </li>
          <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
            <small>203</small>
          </li>
          <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
            <small>203</small>
          </li>
          <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
            <small>245</small>
          </li>
          <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
            <small>203</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>


      <svg style="display: none;">
        <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px" width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
          <path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
                              C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
                              C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
                              c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
                              c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
                              c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
                              c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
                              c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
                              c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
                              c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
                              C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
                              c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
                              L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
                              c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
                              C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
                              C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
                              c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z" />
        </symbol>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
      <div class="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>Overall LB</mark>
            <small>3115</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes1</mark>
            <small>3101</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight1</mark>
            <small>2192</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick1</mark>
            <small>2145</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox1</mark>
            <small>2103</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>And1rew Fox1</mark>
            <small>2103</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Tre1vor McCormick1</mark>
            <small>2145</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox1</mark>
            <small>2103</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- login tab end defaulters -->
    <div id="defaulters" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
      <div class="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>Defaulters</mark>
            <small>3115</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes2</mark>
            <small>31012</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight2</mark>
            <small>21922</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>And1rew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Tre1vor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- login tab end co-workers -->
    <div id="co-workers" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
      <div class="leaderboard">

        <ol>
          <li>
            <mark>co-workers</mark>
            <small>3115</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Brandon Barnes2</mark>
            <small>31012</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Raymond Knight2</mark>
            <small>21922</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Trevor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>And1rew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Tre1vor McCormick2</mark>
            <small>21452</small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <mark>Andrew Fox2</mark>
            <small>21032</small>
          </li>

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
  <!-- tab-content -->

</div>



<!-- Popup -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Oliver Fulco</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><strong>Email Address:</strong> ofulco@fakeemail.com</p>
         <p><strong>IM:</strong> ofulco</p>
          <p><strong>Member Since:</strong> 09/20/2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /form -->

<script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var block = _this.attr('href');
    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
    _this.parent().addClass("active");
    $(".leadboardcontent").hide();
    $(block).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

CSS

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
  background: #c1bdba;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}
.form {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 305px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a0b3b0;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #ff8566;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background: #ff5c33;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
/*--------------------
            Body
            --------------------*/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  min-height: 650px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
/*--------------------
            Leaderboard
            --------------------*/

.leaderboard {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  width: 285px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a404d, #181c26);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a404d, #181c26);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px rgba(62, 9, 11, 0.3);
}
.leaderboard h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 12px 13px 18px;
}
.leaderboard h1 svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.leaderboard ol {
  counter-reset: leaderboard;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.leaderboard ol li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  counter-increment: leaderboard;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  list-style: none;
}
.leaderboard ol li::before {
  content: counter(leaderboard);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #c24448;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: -9px;
  border-top: 10px solid #c24448;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -9px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
.leaderboard ol li small {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
.leaderboard ol li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fa6855;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fa6855;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1)::after {
  background: #fa6855;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #e0574f;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2)::after {
  background: #e0574f;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::after {
  border-top: 6px solid #ba4741;
  bottom: -7px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #d7514d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3)::after {
  background: #d7514d;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::after {
  border-top: 2px solid #b0433f;
  bottom: -3px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) {
  background: #c24448;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8)::after {
  background: #c24448;
  box-shadow: 0 -2.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::after {
  top: -9px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #993639;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: visible;
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
  transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
}
.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
```